# Удалить определённый элемент массива

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть массив состоящий из 5 символов вот таких `["1","2","3","4","5"]`
Как удалить допустим элемент с индексом 3 чтобы выводило уже не так `1,2,3,4,5`, вот так `1,2,3,5`?

```
List list = Arrays.asList(ar1.length);
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(list);
date.remove(8);
Map<String, Object> map;
for (int i = 0; i < list; i++) {
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("hour", ar1[i]);
map.put("min",ar[i]);
date.add(map);
}
```

Помогите выделяет лист в цикле

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Количество элементов в массиве не редактируется (только через пересоздание массива).

Но можно привести `Array` к `ArrayList` и вырезать ненужный элемент:

```
List list = Arrays.asList(array);
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<>(list);
arraylist.remove(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

В Java массив имеет постоянный размер. Из него ничего нельзя удалить, ничего нельзя добавить.
Можно только создать новый массив и скопировать из старого только нужное.
Так сделаем это для разнообразия с помощью Stream API:

```
String[] a = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
int removeIndex = 3;

a = Stream.concat(                       // Объединить
    Arrays.stream(a).limit(removeIndex), // элементы до удаляемого
    Arrays.stream(a).skip(removeIndex+1) // элементы после удаляемого
).toArray(String[]::new);                // в новый массив

System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
```